# Why does "length" work in "expr" under Bash?

Tags: bash

Here, `$expr length  "geekss"  "<"  5  "|"  19  -  6  ">"  10` ouputs:

> 1

while, `$expr length  "geekss"  "<"  5  "&"  19  -  6  ">"  10` outputs:

> 0

I am a bit confused about the deductions. How does `length` work under `expr`?

Comment: It's a feature of the program, see [the man page](https://manpages.org/expr). Incidentally bash matters to the quoting needed to pass the arguments to the program, but does not affect the program itself.

Comment: Before bash (in Bourne-shell, etc.) `expr` (not `$expr`) was the way to find the length of a string (or match to a regex, or extract a substring, or find the index of the first character in a given list within a string). Bash provides `${#var}` to return the length of the string in `var` which is far more efficient than calling `expr`. See [man 1 expr](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expr.1.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two commands (assuming you're showing `$` as your prompt and not as a variable expansion) is the change from `|` to `&`.  The *similarities* in the two statements are:

- `length "geekss" < 5` is false in both cases
- `19 - 6 > 10` is true in both cases

The change in output comes as a result of your change in [logical tests](https://manpages.org/expr):

- `|` is an "OR", which evaluates to *"ARG1 if it is neither null nor 0, otherwise ARG2"*
- `&` is an "AND", which evaluates to *"ARG1 if neither argument is null or 0, otherwise 0"*

In your case, the `|` variation is evaluating to the truth of `19 - 6 > 10` while the `&` variation sees that `length "geekss" < 5` is 0 (false) and so returns 0.

Answer (score 2):

> How does length work under expr?

It gets the length of the string `geekss`. The string `geekss` has 6 characters, so `length "geekss"` is 6.

The `man expr` page seems also to be clear:

```
   length STRING
          length of STRING
```